# Jssor slider responsiveness not working when placed inside a table

Tags: jssor, responsiveness

When you make Jssor slider responsive and it's elements placed inside a Table, responsiveness not working anymore.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var options = {};                            
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);

    //responsive code begin
    //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales
    //while window resizing
    function ScaleSlider() {
        var parentWidth = $('#slider1_container').parent().width();
        if (parentWidth) {
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
        }
        else
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }
    //Scale slider after document ready
    ScaleSlider();

    //Scale slider while window load/resize/orientationchange.
    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    //responsive code end
});
</script>
```

and html:

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
<!-- Slides Container -->
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    <div><img u="image" src="image1.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img u="image" src="image2.jpg" /></div>
</div>
<!-- Trigger -->
<script>jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');</script>
```

If i place "slider1_container" inside a table, the responsiveness won't work anymore.
Im creating a slider webpart for SharePoint and i don't control over the parent of "slider1_container" and any html element could be there.
And because of that table, this line of code never returns a value smaller than the initial width of slider:

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
```

And that's why the responsiveness will fail, because if width not get any smaller then $ScaleWidth method will not scale the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i'm creating a slider web part for SharePoint, i solved this problem by finding another Div element that is parent of the table which causing the issue.
And in this line i set element id of my savior div element like:

```
var parentWidth = $('#savior_parent').width();
```